# Are transmission axles hardened?

Tags: axle

The car I'm rebuilding, an old Skoda Estelle, uses a key in the tip to secure the hub. I want to change that to axles and hubs with splines. However I did the "file" test in the old axle, and with a couple of file strokes I could do a good dent in there, so I guess it is not [hardened](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardened_steel). I also see dent marks made with a chisel, to rough the surface so the bearing would fit. Other indication that perhaps it is not hardened?

The guys that can do me new axles say because their length, they can't fit it inside their furnace...

Other thing I can try is to fill up the hole tip by arc welding, then machine it for splines.

Comment: What year is the car you're working on? Is this a standard or auto transmission?

Comment: Skoda Estelle (120), '80...standard transmission, RWD, independent transaxles that runs inside half housings (no CV)